# Practicing encryption and have 1 character off

Tags: python, encryption

Write a script that inputs a line of plaintext and a distance value and outputs an encrypted text using a Caesar cipher.

The script should work for any printable characters.

An example of the program input and output is shown below:

```
Enter a message: Hello world!
Enter the distance value: 4
Lipps${svph%
```

Here's my coding:

```
# Encryptioin
org_message = input("Enter a message: ")
dist_value = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
code_message = ""
for ch in org_message:
    order_value = ord(ch)
    cipher_value = order_value + dist_value
    if cipher_value > ord('z'):
        cipher_value = ord('a')+dist_value - \
                      (ord('z') - order_value + 1)
    code_message += chr(cipher_value)
print(code_message)
```

My code works but for some reason with this specific entry I get an output of:

```
Lipps$asvph%
```

So instead of '{' I get an 'a'

After getting help I edited the lines to:

```
if cipher_value > ord('~'):
        cipher_value = ord(' ')+dist_value - \
                      (ord('~') - order_value + 1)
```

Comment: Hint: `ord('{')` is greater than `ord('z')`.

Comment: Your the man! That's what I get for coding str8 from a book lol.... on that note I was able to change it up with the z now being ~ and the a being ! getting me what I was looking for.... my question now would be how to include NULL and Dec values 0 to 31?

Comment: Usually when trying to code this you first convert the character to encrypt to a zero based index in an alphabet (which is a broader concept than the 'abc'), then perform modular addition / subtraction (mod n where n is the size of the alphabet) and then convert back again. Which characters are in the alphabet is then up to you (although NULL is not a character and you already included decimal zero).